# Unit Test непонятный результат при тесте RX Java

Tags: android, юнит-тесты, junit, rxjava2

Есть вот такой тест.

```
@Test
fun needShowOnboarding() {
    val cards = listOf(
        mockCard(cardUcid = "1", pinSet = false),
        mockCard(cardUcid = "2", pinSet = true),
        mockCard(cardUcid = "3", pinSet = true)
    )
    val account = mockBankAccount(cards)

    val testObserver = pinSetCardCheker.getOnboardingShowingMode(listOf(account)).test()

    with(testObserver) {
        assertNoErrors()
        assertValueCount(1)
        assertResult(PinSetOnboardingShowingMode.Single("1"))
    }
}
```

По факту должен возвращаться вот такой объект `PinSetOnboardingShowingMode.Single("1")` и он возвращается, но только тест постоянно падает с ошибкой:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Values at position 0 differ; expected: ...PinSetOnboardingShowingMode$Single@5ec77191 (class: Single) but was: ...PinSetOnboardingShowingMode$Single@4642b71d (class: Single) (latch = 0, values = 1, errors = 0, completions = 1)
Expected :...PinSetOnboardingShowingMode$Single@5ec77191 (class: Single) 
Actual   :...PinSetOnboardingShowingMode$Single@4642b71d (class: Single) (latch = 0, values = 1, errors = 0, completions = 1)
```

Если открыть разницу между сравниваемыми объектами то мы видим следующее:

- `...PinSetOnboardingShowingMode$Single@5ec77191 (class: Single)`
- `...PinSetOnboardingShowingMode$Single@4642b71d (class: Single) (latch = 0, values = 1, errors = 0, completions = 1)`

И вот для меня остается загадкой откуда в полученном объекте вот это:

*"(latch = 0, values = 1, errors = 0, completions = 1)"*.

Вот собственно сам класс **PinSetOnboardingShowingMode**:

```
sealed class PinSetOnboardingShowingMode {
    object None : PinSetOnboardingShowingMode()
    class Single(val cardUcid: String) : PinSetOnboardingShowingMode()
    class List(val cardUcidsWithoutPin: ArrayList<String>) : PinSetOnboardingShowingMode()
}
```

До тех пор пока этот же метод (`getOnboardingShowingMode`) возвращал `boolean` вместо `PinSetOnboardingShowingMode` то тест работал успешно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Метод assertResult сравнивает объекты и судя по хэшкодам в результате теста они разные. Это произошло из-за того что в sealed class PinSetOnboardingShowingMode вы используете обычный class вместо data class, у которого автоматом переопределены методы equals и hashcode.
Либо переопрелелите их у Single либо используйте data class.

Comment: Ну да логично. Чёт в голову не пришло. Спасибо